# Drools - Rule execution via KIE server REST not giving response

Tags: drools, drools-kie-server, kie-server

I'm attempting to execute a rule that was authored using Drools Workbench (business-central-7.17.0.Final-wildfly14.war) via KIE execution server (kie-server-7.17.0.Final-ee7.war), I don't get the expected response when I execute the rule using Postman, REST client.

I've tried setting request headers "`X-KIE-ContentType  XSTREAM`", setting payload tag `<insert out-identifier="Employee" return-object="true" entry-point="DEFAULT">` where `out-identifier="Employee"` is the fact.

Request Payload

```
<batch-execution lookup="TestBaseSession">
  <insert out-identifier="Employee" return-object="true" entry-point="DEFAULT">
  <com.test.Employee>
    <iEmpId>27</iEmpId>
    <strName></strName>
  </com.test.Employee>
  </insert>
  <fire-all-rules/>
</batch-execution>
```

Rule file

```
package com.test;
import com.test.Employee;

//This is the first rule
rule "001"
    when
        emp : Employee(iEmpId==27)
    then
        emp.setStrName("FooBar");
        insert(emp);
        //System.out.println("DDDDD");
end
```

I expect the output to be something like below (or similar to it),

```
<response type="SUCCESS" msg="Container Test_1.0.0 successfully called.">
    <result class="execution-results">
        <result identifier="Employee">
            <com.test.Employee>
                <iEmpId>27</iEmpId>
                <strName>FooBar</strName>
            </com.test.Employee>
        </result>
        <fact-handle identifier="Employee" external-form="0:1:850421248:850421248:1:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:com.test.Employee"/>
    </result>
</response>
```

But I didn't get the expected, nor the System.out message isn't printed in Wildfly console, which suggests that the rule isn't executed? any suggestions would be really helpful.